# C# Treeview Control loses focus after Sort method called

Tags: c#, sorting, treeview, focus

when the user adds or edits a node in my Treeview, I wish to resort the nodes in the TreeView which I am dong via a custom Compare method in a class inheriting from IComparer.

The only issue is, once I call the Sort method on the treeview in the AfterLabelEdit event, the TreeView does not regain focus.

I've tried setting the TreeView as the forms active control but this doesn't work.

Any

Answer (score 0):

Try setting treeview.SelectedNode to the selected node (gleaned from the event), then calling the Focus() method on the TreeView control.

Ex:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeView tv;

void tv_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    tv.SelectedNode = e.Node;
    tv.Focus();
}
```